# Angular2 で複数のTypeScriptファイルをひとつにまとめるには？

Tags: angularjs, gulp, typescript

Angular2公式[チュートリアル３](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html)を見ると、下記の４つ .ts ファイルがありますが、

- app.component.ts
- boot.ts
- hero.ts
- hero-detail.component.ts

例えば `app.component.ts` を見ると、下記のように import しています。

```
import {Hero} from './hero';
import {HeroDetailComponent} from './hero-detail.component';
```

gulp でコンパイルを *.ts として個別に行うのはもちろん問題はないのですが、ひとつの.jsファイルにまとめたい場合はどのようにすればよいでしょうか？
はじめにまとめてロードすることで、HTTPリクエストを減らしたいと思っています。

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript 1.8でAMDやsystemモジュールを1ファイルに結合できるようになるそうですが、現状まだ無理なので、moduleをcommonjsでコンパイルしbrowserifyを使うとまとめられます。

```
//tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "ES5",
  "module": "system",
...


$ npm i browserify
$ npm run tsc
$ ./node_modules/.bin/browserify app/boot.js -o app/app.js
```

Answer (score 1):

tsconfig.jsonで `compilarOptions`の`out`プロパティに出力先ファイル名を指定すればimportやrequireが解決されて結合された状態でコンパイルされます。